# Android - tablet to phone screensize

Tags: android-layout, android

I have an app that has a screen like this (on a 10" tablet) :

[image]

Now I need to amend the app to also work on a phone. As the screens will be smaller, I want to take the "split view" UI and change it so that the left hand side list view is shown on its own, then on selecting a row the appropriate right hand side list view is then shown.

How do I handle this in the app, as one activity currently handles both listviews, and I guess the phone will need two one for each listview.

How do I detect which one to do?

thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

See [Supporting Different Screen Sizes](http://developer.android.com/training/multiscreen/screensizes.html#TaskUseSWQuali).

Typically this is done using Fragments, but the basic idea is the same whether you use fragments or not. You create two different layouts for your Activity depending on the screen size.

- Save the default layout single-pane for phones at `res/layout/activity_main.xml`
- Save the dual-pane tablet layout at `res/layout/activity_main_twopane.xml`

Then you use layout alias files with the screen size qualifiers described in the link to determine when the tablet layout should be used. For example to show the dual-pane layout on `large` screens and on screens with at least 600dp in the widest direction (includes large screen phones such as the Galaxy S3), you could do this:

- `res/values-large/layout.xml` contains:

  ```
  <resources>
      <item name="activity_main" type="layout">@layout/activity_main_twopane</item>
      <bool name="twopane">true</bool>
  </resources>
  ```
- `res/values-sw600dp/layout.xml` contains:

  ```
  <resources>
      <item name="activity_main" type="layout">@layout/activity_main_twopane</item>
      <bool name="twopane">true</bool>
  </resources>
  ```

The Android system will take care of loading the proper layout file (either `res/layout/activity_main.xml` or `res/layout/activity_main_twopane.xml`) when your Activity loads the layout:

```
setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
```

Just remember that the views that don't exist in the single-pane layout will be null when you try to access them (e.g., there won't be two `ListView`s anymore). Checking whether a certain View exists is one way to detect which layout you are using.

Also note the use of optional [Boolean resources in XML files](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/resources/more-resources.html#Bool). This is a handy way to pass the "is it a large screen or small screen" variable to your Java code. You can access Boolean resources in your Activity like this:

```
boolean isTwoPane = getResources().getBoolean(R.bool.twopane);
```

Answer (score 1):

You should have a look at the MasterDetailedFlow Navigation template. Eclipse:NewProject>check create Activity>select "MasterDetailedFlow" Navigatoin type. Have a look at [Data Binding](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6007941/android-data-binding-similar-to-wpf) on Android

Comment: Also see http://developer.android.com/training/basics/fragments/fragment-ui.html and http://developer.android.com/training/multiscreen/adaptui.html